# Best approach(es) or technolog(y/ies) for this specific problem?

Tags: web-services

I have a web-based interface for handing invoices, customer records and other transaction records which interacts currently with a database of all the aforementioned stored upon the same machine. As you can imagine, this is quite a simple set-up consisting of a web-app (PHP) and a database (MySQL). However, the ideal scenario is to keep the records on the machine they are currently on (easy) and move the web-app to another server within the same network (again, easy) ... but in addition, provide facilities on a public-facing website for managing accounts by customers and so forth. The problem is this - the public-facing web server is located in a completely separate location as it is a dedicated server provided by a well-known ISP.

What would be the best way to enable the records to be accessible from this other server whilst ensuring that all communications are secure. Speed is not a huge factor, although any outages on either side should be handled gracefully. Initially my thoughts went towards web services (XML-RPC/SOAP/[Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/)), but these options seem to present difficulties (security being the main one, overcomplexity as well).

The web-app must remain PHP-based. The public-facing site is likely to be PHP-based as well, although Python (likely using Django) is another option. The introduction of any other technologies (Java etc) is not a problem, although it is preferred if they be Linux-friendly (so .NET would not be the best fit here).

Apologies if this question is somewhat verbose and vague. I am testing the water somewhat in regards to this kind of problem. Any advice or suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar.  You can expose a web service to the internet that will do the database access, but requests to the service must match a strong hashed and salted password (which will be secured on the ISP's server in the DMZ.)

Either this or some sort of public/private key encryption scheme.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this might seem a bit silly, but what if you just used mysql replication?

Instead of using all sorts of fancy web services, just have a master sql server on one machine, then have it replicate to another server that holds the slave sql server as well as the web app

Comment: I must admit I hadn't considered that. However the reason I wanted to go down some kind of service route is because I don't want to copy the entire customer database to the public web server. Also, does mysql replication take place across a secured connection or could it be read off the wire?

Comment: It's most likely better to use an existing robust enterprise tested solution rather than roll your own. 

Replication transactions can be secured using SSL thereby effectively preventing any sniffing or MitM attacks